# Possible to change name in a query to uppercase

Tags: apex, soql, query

I want to query for accounts based on what the user types in a text field but rather than being totally dependent on the user to come through and type it correctly (lower or upper case) what I want to do is query the right opportunities with names that are equal in upper case.

This is what I have but you can't do this

```
List<Account> temp = [Select Name,ID,LastModifiedByID from Account WHERE Name.toUpperCase =: searchField ORDER BY LastModifiedDate Asc];
```

For ex. 
User enters "Hello" (name of opportunity is HeLLo) 
What I want to do is query it in a way that I compare HELLO and HELLO so I return the right results.

I'm not sure if this is possible. Another way I thought was querying all opportunities and comparing within a loop but that will be outrageous when I have a large number of records to process

Answer (score 7):

Queries filter in a case-insensitive manner. There's no need to convert either operand to uppercase to get the correct results; however, keep in mind that you need to use "LIKE" if you want to find part of the full field's value.

```
Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE :'%'+searchTerm+'%'];
```

If you're having problems with a *query*, consider using a *search* instead:

```
Opportunity[] opps = [FIND :searchTerm IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(Name)][0];
```

From the SOSL, you can then pull in all matching accounts:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Name, LastModifiedById FROM Account
                      WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity
                          WHERE Id IN :opps)];
```

Comment: What do you mean by `keep in mind that you need to use "LIKE" if you want to find part of the full field's value.`?

Comment: @user2582622 For example, given "searchTerm" of "Hello", `Name = :searchTerm` will not match "Hello World", but will match "HeLlO". You need to use LIKE if you want to find just part of the field's value; "Hello%" will match "HELLO World", for example.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you're saying. I'm assuming if its 'Hello WOrLd' then it will match, correct?

Comment: @user2582622 You got it. Use "=" for case-insensitive match of the full field contents, and "LIKE" for a partial match.

Comment: Can you actually mix bind expressions and literals like that?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, you can use any legal apex code when binding, even using methods inside inline apex, like: `[select name from account where id in :accountMap.keySet()]` or `[select id from account where name in :myutils.somemethod(withparams)]`. This does not work in dynamic queries (Database.* methods).

Comment: Yes, I know how bind expressions work, generally. I've used functions in them for years and I already knew you couldn't do dynamic binding in such a manner. What I didn't realize is that you can concatenate literals in and have it still count as a bind expression.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, it's a full expression evaluation system. You can even do math operations and what-have-you. It's awfully useful.